# Why does this theorem fail for arbitrarily large n?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading the following theorem in complex analysis:

> **Theorem D.** Suppose that $f(z)$ is regular in the circle $|z-z_0|\leq R$, and has $n$ zeros (at least) in $|z-z_0|\leq r (< R)$. Then, if $f(z_0)\neq0$,
> $$
> \left(\frac Rr\right)^n\leq\frac M{|f(z_0)|},\tag{12}
> $$
> where $M$ is the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on $|z-z_0|=R$.

Multiple zeros are (as always) counted according to their order of multiplicity.

My doubt is in the theorem,  we are taking atleast $n$ zeros. So for example if $f$ has $1000$ zeros and i can consider only $10$ zeros in the inner circle. Now as the theorem should be true for any number of zeros, by increasing $n$(this i can take by keeping $M$ and $f(z_0)$ constant, by multiplying a suitable factor for $f(z)$ to increase the number of zeros.), L.H.S. increases(as $r<R$) and this seems that the inequality breaks at some point.I am unable to understand where i am making mistake.

For reference i am even giving the proof of the theorem:

> We may suppose $z_0=0$, since the general case reduces to this by the substitution $z=z_0+z'$. Suppose $f(z)$ has zeros at the points $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ in $|z|\leq r$ (multiple zeros being allowed for by repetition). Then
> $$
> f(z)=\phi(z)\prod_{\nu=1}^{n}\frac{R(z-a_\nu)}{R^2-\bar a_\nu z},
> $$
> where $\bar a_\nu$ is the conjugate of $a_\nu$, and $\phi(z)$ is regular in $|z|\leq R$. On $|z|=R$ each factor of $\prod$ has modulus $1$; hence
> $$
> |\phi(z)|=|f(z)|\leq M\qquad(|z|=R).
> $$
> Since $\phi(z)$ is regular in $|z| \leq R$, it follows (by the maximum modulus principle or by Cauchy's inequalities) that $|\phi(0)| \leq M$. Hence $$|f(0)| = |\phi(0)| \prod_{\nu=1}^n \frac{a_\nu}{R} \leq M \left(\frac r R\right)^n \textrm{,}$$ which proves the theorem, since $f(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: When you multiply by factors to increase the number of zeros, you will increase the maximum $M$ on the boundary, so the RHS increases as well.

Answer (score 2):

> So for example if $f$ has $1000$ zeros and I can consider only $10$ zeros in the inner circle.

Yes, you can do that: use the theorem with $n=10$ instead of $n=1000$. This does not give you anything new, however. Since
$$\left(\frac Rr\right)^{10}\le \left(\frac Rr\right)^{1000}$$
the inequality 
$\left(\frac Rr\right)^{10}\le \frac M{|f(z_0)|}$ is a consequence of 
$\left(\frac Rr\right)^{1000}\le \frac M{|f(z_0)|}$.

In general, decreasing the value of $n$ in the inequality $$\left(\frac Rr\right)^n\leq\frac M{|f(z_0)|}\tag{12}$$
makes for a the left hand side  smaller, and therefore the inequality becomes weaker.

> increasing $n$ (this I can take by keeping $M$ and $f(z_0)$ constant, by multiplying a suitable factor for $f(z)$ to increase the number of zeros.

It is not at all clear how you plan to introduce extra factors in $f$ (i.e., change $f$) while keeping both $\max_{|z|=R}|f(z)|$ and $|f(z_0)|$ same as they were. The inequality (12) places a bound on your ability to do so.